# Is it possible to get grunt-usemin to only make html changes?

Tags: grunt-usemin

I am currently involved in a project where I am using require js.
In my gruntfile I am using requirejs to produce a single optimised js file.
I want to create a single css file to go with that and I want to use grunt-usemin for this.

My problem is that usemin doesn't seem to want to transform javascript import statements in my index.html without attemting to transform the javascript as well.

```
<script src="bower_components/requirejs/require.js" data-main="app/main.js"></script>
```

I desperately want usemin to change this to:

```
<script src="main.js"></script>
```

,but not make any changes to the javascript.
Is this possible? Right now useminPrepare stop at my script import with the error "require.js blocks are no more supported."

I tried configuring an 'empty' flow for useminPrepare ('flow': {'html': {'steps': {'js': []}}}) but this sadly didn't work.

If these tasks are impossible to combine for usemin, than suggestions for other grunt plugins i could use instead (or in addition) would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to avoid the problems with usemin and started using grunt-regex-replace to change the script import.

Gruntfile.coffee:

```
'regex-replace':
      html:
        src: ['<%= settings.tempDirectory %>/index.html']
        actions:[
          search: '<script src="bower_components/requirejs/require.js" data-main="app/main"></script>'
          replace: '<script src="main"></script>'
        ]
```